# Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS Gnome Control Centre error dbus-launch

Tags: gnome, software-center, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu Desktop on my MacBook Pro.
I went into Gnome Control Centre and wanted to move my dock to the bottom of the desktop, so I did this. Afterward I tried to use Gnome Control Centre again but it does not open. When I try opening it through the terminal it gives me this error: Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory)
I also keep getting popups about there being an internal error, so I have sent these to Ubuntu.
Please could someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The error code said there's no "dbus-launch" file found in system. By searching in https://packages.ubuntu.com/ page under the "`Search the contents of packages`" section,     **dbus-x11** is the package which contains the file.

So, press **Ctrl+Alt+T** on keyboard to open terminal,  and try running command to install the `dbus-x11` package to fix it:

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```